# Drawing line between dynamic buttons across relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_one"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.7">

        <Button android:id="@+id/buttonhome1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:clickable="true"
             android:focusable="false"
             android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
             android:background="@drawable/"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttonhome1"
            android:text="@string/Main"/> 

     </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_two"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_weight="1.8">

        <Button android:id="@+id/childBtn1"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:focusable="true" 
             android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
             android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
             android:background="@drawable/"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/childtxt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerVertical="@+id/childBtn1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/childBtn1"
            android:text="@string/text1"/>  

        <Button android:id="@+id/childBtn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height=  "wrap_content"
            android:focusable="true" 
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/childBtn1"
            android:background="@drawable/"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/childtxt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/childBtn1"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/childBtn2"
            android:text="@string/text2"/>  

    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_three"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.8" />
     <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_four"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_weight="1.7"/>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Drawing line between dynamic buttons

I have three relative layout in my linear layout.

`Layout 1` has main button, when click action performed on main button generating dynamic buttons in relative `layout 2` through code.

My question is that can I connect main button with its sub buttons in `layout 2` using graphics class by means of drawing lines across layouts in dynamic way?

Comment: You can add a view with black(as you need) background and with layout_width = "match_parent", layout_height="1dp" in the relative layout as you adding the buttons.

Comment: I use `TextView` to draw line with `background` color and `height = 2dp` :D

Comment: If i do so ,line will be adeed as element only in tht particular layout.How does it connects from layout 1 to layout2.Layouts are separated using layout_weight.Eg: i need something like node tree in my layout

Comment: Post our xml for better understanding of question.

Answer (score 2):

Set id to your dynamic buttons and use the addRule() with the id of the button to add the line below your button.

```
    RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_relative_layout);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    // your button here
    Button tv1 = new Button(this);
    tv1.setText("Hello");
    tv1.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    tv1.setId(1);//id of the button
    rLayout.addView(tv1);
   // line here
   RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lineparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1);
   View line = new View(this);
   lineparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 1);//specify the id of the button to add the line below the button
   line.setLayoutParams(lineparams);
   line.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
   line.setId(2);
   rLayout.addView(line);
```

Comment: Thanks sripathi...But my requirement is different.have split linear layout horizontally with three relative layout.These relative layout i have dynamic buttons.Now i need to connect as line from button in relative layout1 to other buttons in relative layout 2.

Comment: Are you using Relative layout to hold the button alone? Else you have some other views there?